# How to set default value for kendo dropdown filter in grid's header

Tags: c#, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

The situation is follow: we have a kendo grid with columns, in one column we have a kendo dropdown for filtering purposes. Client side based on angularjs, server side on c#. So, is it possible to set default value for kendo dropdown without knowing it's id? I'm searching the second day and cant find anything in web/teletrik documentation.

Code

```
$scope.GridOptions =
            {
                pageable: { refresh: true, pageSizes: true },
                columns: [
                    // other columns here
                    {
                        field: "RegistrationStatus", title: "Status", width: 13,
                        filterable: {
                            operators: {
                                string: {
                                    eq: "Is equal to",
                                    neq: "Is not equal to"
                                }
                            },
                            ui: function(element) {
                                element.kendoDropDownList({
                                    dataSource: [
                                        { Name: "Registered", Value: "PassedInterview" },
                                        { Name: "Pending", Value: "PassedInterview" },
                                        { Name: "Rejected", Value: "Rejected" }
                                    ],
                                    dataTextField: "Name",
                                    dataValueField: "Value",
                                    optionLabel: "--Select Status--"
                                    defaultValue: "PassedInterview" // smth like this, is this possible? or achieve in any other methods instead of taking dropdown id, which I dont know because this is hided inside
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                selectable: 'row',
                editable: 'inline'
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it to work setting the [`value`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#methods-value) after its initialization:

```
element.data("kendoDropDownList").value("PassedInterview");
```

[Demo.](http://dojo.telerik.com/EpEqE) Note that you can also use [`select()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#methods-select) method if you like.

The problem is, idk why but you can't call it right after the widget creation, you have to use `window.setTimeout()`. I know, its ugly. But somewhere between the creation and the showing proccess your function is somewhat *ignored* and doesn't works if called directly. That is why the timer(try w/o it and check it out by yourself).

I have also tried to set `value` and `index` in the creation params, but none worked(they actually should).

Comment: thank you for answer, yeah value & index is not worked, dont know why. The value is shown, but value it's not binded to it. missed element.data("kendoDropDownList").trigger("change"); one day kendo save a lot of time in another makes crazy %)

Comment: @Rakstit sure. Some things on kendo doesn't really makes sense at all. I have this `setTimeout` trick because I had to use it in other ocasions.